# Show modal before DataTables JQuery starts ASP NET

Tags: ajax, server, datatables, backend, configure

I'm using DataTables JQuery 1.10.18 in an ASP NET Project.

I need to show a modal dialog BEFORE the datatable has any data and hide it AFTER all the Datatables proccess has finished.

This second part is resolved by

```
initComplete: function (settings, json) {
           $('#loading').modal('hide');
        }
```

where 'loading' is the ID of the modal.

However, my problem is showing it before all the data is bound in the gridview or, in any case, after it was bound to the gridview but the datatables's styles has NOT been applied.

I want to do something like this:

retrieve data - bind to gridview - SHOW MODAL - apply Datatable styles - close modal.

All the logic for applying Datatables it's done and it works. I only have the problem that it takes many seconds to be applied.

Of course I've tried

```
       $('#loading').modal('show');
```

before calling the functions that configure the datatables but the modal shows AFTER all the configuration is done.
I've also tried using promises, callbacks, settimeout but it was always the same.

**A clarification**

We cannot use AJAX to make the request because of the project's backend structure. We have the issue that we decided to implement Datatable after the project began. **I clarify this because we're aware of Datatable it's good at integrating the server-side-process with AJAX but, for us, it's not (sadly) an option.**

Answer (score 0):

Try this ! put your datatable inside a div like this:

```
<div id="tableDiv" hidden>
// your table
</div>
```

then when your datatable is loaded make it visible like this:

```
$("#yourtable").prop("hidden",false);
```

**Edit:** Also Use this function to know when your table finish the draw event

```
$('#someTable').on( 'draw.dt', function(){
     if (! example.data().any() ) {
          console.log("empty");
        }else {
          console.log("not empty"); 
         //display your table here ?
        }
    });
```

Hope it helps

Comment: That's an option but it's not what I was really looking for. The main problem is the time the user has to wait until the application show some data. If I hide the datatable the user may think that something went wrong. I know it's a matter of seconds but it's not good for user experience.
I know I could add another loading modal in each web form but it means adding more complexity to the application. Nowaday all the Datatables issue it's being managed by a single Javascript file and, if it's possible, I'd like to keep it like that.

Comment: @GreatNews why you dont add some vanilla animation? so the user will know that the data is loading ?

Comment: I've also tried that. However, it's still not working. The animation/modal/whatever appears AFTER the Datatable script is executed.

Comment: @GreatNews try to use setTimeout ? that will help you to display the table after some seconds

Comment: the thing is the datatable is loaded in codebehind and its loading is fast. My issue is when I apply datatables script.